# not able to access label text

Tags: asp.net

Please take a look at my code. I'm not able to access the value of the `Label` text in the `Button1_Click`, event but am able to access `TextBox` text that is set in the `use` function:

```
public partial class productDetail : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {       

        int i = int.Parse(TextBox1.Text);
        int pr = int.Parse(Label4.Text);

        string s2 = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
        string s1 = Request.QueryString["pName"];

        Label1.Text = s1;
        Label5.Text += Label4.Text;
    }

    protected void use(object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
    {
        Label prd = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("productNameLabel");
        Label1.Text += prd.Text;

        Label brd = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("brandLabel");
        Label2.Text += brd.Text;

        Image img = (Image)e.Item.FindControl("Image1");
        Label3.Text += img.ImageUrl.ToString();

        Label prc = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("priceLabel");
        Label4.Text = prc.Text;
    }
}
```

Comment: It would help us out a lot if you posted your markup and used control IDs that are more descriptive than `Label1` through `Label5`. It's hard to tell what you're trying to accomplish with these generic names.

Answer (score 2):

I think you forgot the `runat="server"` from the label.

**Edit:** why dont you set the labels like this:

```
protected void use(object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
{
    Label1.Text += productNameLabel.Text;
    Label2.Text += brandLabel.Text;
    Label3.Text += Image1.ImageUrl.ToString();
    Label4.Text = priceLabel.Text;
}
```

(ask these type of questions in the class instead)

Comment: Then edit your question. Which label can't you access? and use punctuation marks please.

Comment: label1,2,3 
label 4 written there is not a label its a text box its text is accessible

Comment: i'm not not set the label like u said because that productNameLabel,brandLabel,Image1,priceLabel are defined inside datalist control and all date created on run time so thats not available in this event inside i'm writing code.